# Db.saveChanges() issue show wrong message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4

After I submit my forms I got this error : `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST.PK_CITOYEN) violated` `db.saveChanges()` line :
That's my Action :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateCit(CITOYEN citoyen)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CITOYEN.Add(citoyen);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
            resultModel.ResultType = TypeOfResult.Success;
            //my french is a bit rusty but the result from Google Translate sounds good enough
            resultModel.Message = "Citoyen ajouté avec succès.";

            return View("Index", resultModel);
        }

        ViewBag.REGION_ID = new SelectList(db.REGION, "REGION_ID", "NOM", citoyen.REGION_ID);
        return PartialView(citoyen);
    }
```

But the data are successfully added to database. I tried many time always same error message and m data are saved and ther's no simillaire key to my db.

Comment: Probably you are trying to add an object which is already present in the database. Try using `Attach` insted of `Add`.

Comment: This same code works with normal view and all what I done just changed from view to partial view

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your model here?

And also could you please check Entity in debug mode on step when you are adding it.

Looks like you **don't assigning new id (primary key value) to entity ** which you are trying to add, but instead of that **you are adding entity with default value** of id field.